# filter fire-base keys with given value

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, filter

I have a fire base data structured like this:

[image]

I want to list all the keys under candidate_employer that start with  for example "5_" using JavaScript

Comment: Are you currently able to access `candidate_employer` data?

If yes, I'll add an answer below for you

Comment: yes i am able to receive data

Comment: Okay cool. You can get it as follows:
using Object.keys() and passing the values to a filter().

for example:

`Object.keys(candidate_employer).filter(..do your regex comparison here..)`

Should give you the results keys. You can then walk through your data with the resulting keys

Comment: is this client side filter ?

Comment: Yes. Do you have a requirement to do this on the back end?

Comment: yes required to get filtered data from the firebase .. my problem is i don't to get all the data from firebase just the chat log corresponds to the given params (x_y) i have the value x but y not with me

Comment: Okay in that case, you can use the filter functionality provided by Firebase.

I'm not sure how you're running your queries but the firebase api provides the following option: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#filtering-by-key
The SDK also has support for this:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#filter_by_key_or_value

Comment: thank you dear some one put a nice solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
let root = firebase.database().ref();
let ref = root.child("chat/candidate_employer");
let query = ref.orderByKey().startAt("5_").endAt("5~");

query.once("value").then(function(results) {
  results.forEach(function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.key);
  })
})
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [ordering and filtering data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data).

Comment: thnaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaks a lot